# Delete or dissolve face keeping edges

Tags: modeling

Let's say I have a plane, is it possible to delete the face only without touching the edges or vertices? I plan to apply a skin modifier later but don't need the faces.

Can this be applied to any mesh?

Comment: X > Only Faces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, yes, it's in the options when you press <kbd>X</kbd> for delete: **Faces Only**

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, with Faces it was deleting the surrounding edges as well.