Replace circular face with a rectangle?
Is it possible to replace cylinder's circular face with a rectangle? I'd like to keep about the same number of vertices to create a smooth transition.


Easiest way is to subdivide the rectangle to match the number of vertices of the circle,


Then select both and do a Edge > Bridge Edge Loops, increase the number of cuts to smooth the transition.


thanks for the answer. how do I create a rectangle out of the rectangular face? I tried deleting the face, but this deletes all the vertices. And subdividing the face creates additional vertices inside the face and not necessarily on the permiter.

I got it, need to delete "faces only": https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/142976/delete-or-dissolve-face-keeping-edges

Another useful answer was this one, explains how to display the number of selected vertices: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72171/vertex-count-number-display
